# Angular get multiple selected options values

Tags: php, angular

I'm using angular2-multiselect . I'm trying to get the values in post.

```
[(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
```

selectedItems coming as objects. how can take selected values within postname

console.log return

```
 0:{id: "x", itemName: "12"}
 1:{id: "y", itemName: "16"}
```

Comment: Please post a stackblitz example